# Force Destroy of app for testing

Tags: android, eclipse, sharedpreferences, bundle, ondestroy

I think I need some help understanding how `Bundles` are handled on `Destroy`. I have an issue with my App where a `bundle` becomes `null` when its closed overnight or over several hours etc. But i cannot replicate this for debugging purposes. No matter what I do, the bundle remains intact after supposed forced destroys etc

To replicate the issue I've tried two different things:

1. Using the option under Developer options IIRC - `Settings>Developer Options > Don't Keep activities`.
2. Using the "STOP" button under eclipse DDMS.

Neither of these seem to remove the `Bundle`. Am I missing something, how is the bundle retained after a supposed full destroy?

I'm using a Nexus 5, android 4.4.2

I have a check in my "preferences" `class`, which firstly checks if `Bundle` variables are available from a logical previous/parent `Activity`, if not it reads from Android `SharedPreferences`. The problem is I must have an issue when I check the bundle is not `null`. So I need to debug this as its allowing null values to be set from the bundle to my "session" ID's

Am I missing something? Surely the bundle should be destroyed along with my App, but when using option 1) above, the Bundle still exists so i can't debug my IF statement. Option 2) is not useful because the stop button seems just to close the active Activity - my app steps backwards through the hierarchy of screens as I click stop. Again not destroying the entire application from memory. I must be missing something fundamental!

Cheers for any help.

BTW, I've search for all solutions on SO I could, everything just seems to be using the optoins above with no issues, is something possibly different with a my Android OS/Phone?

Edit: This article by Google shows the functionality I need but i assume this is an outdated article and its referring to what I try in option 1)? - 
See "Immediately destroy activities" - developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-devtools.html

Edit2: see the comments below I mistakenly thought the above Google doc was referring to removing an entire application from memory rather than just an Activity. Anyway for now I'll try something like this to check the bundle value

```
Long val = bundle.getLong(Navigator.INTENT_KEY_CHANNEL_ID, 0);
if (val != 0 && val != null) {
}
```

Comment: I've tried to understand your question and failed. It has inaccuracies and incorrect terminology. I assume that the `Bundle` in question is the one passed to your `Activity` constructor by the framework. Why not set it to null in your code before your buggy method?  I don't get what you mean by `Destroy`.  Do you mean the app process is killed?  In any case, I can see no reason why the `Bundle` would be deleted and with the limited context you've provided, conclude that the problem is entirely in your code, which you have not shown, and the question is thus unanswerable.

Comment: I have edited my post for better clarity, I thought I was clear about destroy. I mean I need a way to test that my application is completely removed from memory. Nothing I test seems to provide this functionality. This article by Google shows the functionality I need but i assume this is an outdated article and its referring to what I try in option 1)? - See "Immediately destroy activities" - developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-devtools.html

Comment: "I have edited my post for better clarity" -- Simon read your revised question, as you can tell by the timestamp on his comment. "I thought I was clear about destroy" -- you are neither clear about "destroy" nor "bundle". What `Bundle` are you referring to? The one passed to `onCreate()`? How are you starting your app after stopping the process from DDMS?

Comment: I still don't get it.  Are you confusing destroying activities and your application process.  That link makes no mention of memory usage or the app process.  If you mean the app process, then it's associated virtual machine is also destroyed and there is nothing left in memory, or rather, the memory is completely freed for re-use.

Comment: "This article by Google shows the functionality I need" -- I fail to see how. Activities are not applications or processes.

Comment: Ok I need a means to destroy an Application process, I mistakenly assumed destroying an activity with that method would also destroy its bundle, but i guess a bundle relates to a application not an activity.

Comment: @CommonsWare I definitely confused all this by thinking that Android article was referring to an Application not a single activity Sorry all. Regarding the bundle, i'm referring to the one passed to onCreate(). It contains params passed from the parent activity. At some point if i leave my app overnight, those values in the bundle become null which is what I'm trying to debug. RE starting my app after stopping the process in DDMS, if i have my app open, on a 3rd sub activity, and I click stop it will simply close the current child activity and return to the parent activity. not restarting it

Comment: I think he either means the Bundle that's attached to the Activity's launch Intent or the one passed in the `onCreate()` method of the Activity.

I think the issue here is he's trying to simulate the system forcibly dumping the Application from memory. However, closing the app through most other means it would get a new launch intent when the app is restarted.

Comment: "RE starting my app after stopping the process in DDMS, if i have my app open, on a 3rd sub activity, and I click stop it will simply close the current child activity and return to the parent activity. not restarting it" -- keep pressing STOP until your process no longer returns. Based upon a quick test in a 4.3 emulator, this should be once you have exhausted the BACK stack. At that point, start your app from the home screen launcher, or run it again from your IDE.

Comment: `i guess a bundle relates to a application`  A `Bundle` is a class in it's own right.  It does not `relate` to an application or an activity.  It is simply the class the Android designers chose to use when restoring activity states.  That said, you have introduced a new confusion since the Bundle passed to onCreate is not from the `parent` activity (not that there is any such thing).  Are you referring to the `Intent`?  My recommendation is that you rethink this whole thing, make sure that you understand how it works, and write a new question.

Comment: "Are you referring to the Intent? ". Yes I'm referring to the bundle attached to the intent when loading from activity A to B. For some reason, if the application is left closed over night for example, the bundle values will become "null" in acitivity B. When B onCreate runs after clicking the application Icon from android desktop I have a bug when the bundle's value is validated. What I still fail to understand is how the bundle values are null, and how to forcefully remove the Application from memory yet load straight to Act B. Thanks for all the help though all, I will have to test further.

Answer (score 1):

1- Launch your application

2- Press Home Button

3- Launch DDMS in Android Studio or Eclipse

4- Select your app and click stop

5- Choose your app launched app history

Thanks,